# I want to make alert to show message error in HomeVC

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a function in HomeViewModel to get books from api service using Alamofire .. I want when error occur show alert to show the user error message

here my ViewModel..

> import Foundation
> import RxCocoa
> import RxSwift
> import Alamofire

class HomeViewModel {

```
var loadingBehavior  = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)

private var homeModelSubject = PublishSubject<[Book]>()
private var isTableHidden    = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)

var homeModelObservable: Observable<[Book]> {
    return homeModelSubject
}

var isTableHiddenObservable:Observable<Bool> {
    return isTableHidden.asObservable()
}

func getBooks() {
    
    loadingBehavior.accept(true)
    
    let url = "https://simple-books-api.glitch.me/books"
    
    APIServices.instance.getData(url: url, method: .get, params: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil) {[weak self] (bookModel: [Book]?, baseError: HomeBaseError?, error) in
        
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        self.loadingBehavior.accept(false)
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            
        } else if let baseError = baseError {
            print(baseError)
            
        } else {
            
            guard let books = bookModel else { return }
            if books.count > 0 {
                
                self.homeModelSubject.onNext(books)
                self.isTableHidden.accept(true)
                
            } else {
                self.isTableHidden.accept(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

> here my HomeVC
> import UIKit
> import RxCocoa
> import RxSwift

class HomeVC: UIViewController {

```
let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.separatorColor = .clear
    tableView.rowHeight = 140
    tableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
    return tableView
}()

let homeViewModel = HomeViewModel()
let disposeBage   = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureViewController()
    configureTableView()
    subscribeToLoading()
    subscribeToResponse()
    subscribeToPostSelection()
    getResponse()
    
}

func configureViewController() {
    title = "Home"
    view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
}

func configureTableView() {
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}

func subscribeToLoading() {
    homeViewModel.loadingBehavior.subscribe(onNext: { (isLoading) in
        if isLoading {
            self.showIndicator(withTitle: "loading", and: "")
        } else {
            self.hideIndicator()
        }
    }).disposed(by: disposeBage)
}

func subscribeToResponse() {
    homeViewModel.homeModelObservable.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: HomeTableViewCell.self)) { row,books,cell in
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        cell.titleLabel.text            = books.name
        cell.secondaryTitleLabel.text  = books.type
        if books.available == true {
            cell.avalibaleOrNotLabel.text = "Avalibale"
            cell.avalibaleOrNotStatus.backgroundColor = .green
        } else {
            cell.avalibaleOrNotLabel.text = "Not Avalibale"
            cell.avalibaleOrNotStatus.backgroundColor = .gray
        }
        
    }.disposed(by: disposeBage)
}

func subscribeToPostSelection() {
    Observable.zip(tableView.rx.itemSelected,tableView.rx.modelSelected(Book.self)).bind { selectedIndex , post in
        print(selectedIndex)
    }.disposed(by: disposeBage)
}

func getResponse() {
    homeViewModel.getBooks()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use `closures` as callbacks in your `HomeViewController` . Let me explain.

First Define the closure expression shown below, globally. The point of having it globally is that you can reuse the same expression throughout your app. I've set it as a `typealias` for easy reuse.

```
typealias networkHandler = (Bool, String) -> Void
```

This expression will take a `Bool`, `String` value, both of which will be necessary to decide whether to show an alert or not.

1. Bool - value to represent whether the network call was successful or not (`true` = Successfull, `false` = some interuption).
2. String - the message in string to show if an error occurs

There after, add the `networkHandler` as a parameter to your `getBooks()` method in `HomeViewModel` as follows. After adding it invoke the `handler` where you feel like causes an error or the network call was successful.

```
func getBooks(handler: networkHandler) {
// If the network call was successful
    if success {
        handler(true, "Success")
    }

    // If an error occurs add the handler as follows
    if let error = error {
        handler(false, "Error message\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

After adding this, you will have to change the `getResponse()` method in your `HomeViewController` to look something similar to the following. The XCode auto complete will assist you on this XD.

```
private func getResponse() {
    homeViewModel.getBooks { isSuccessful, message
       if isSuccessful {
           // Do something
           print("successful", message)
       } else {
           // Show the alert message
           showAlert(message: message)   // Define this action as you wish
       }
    }
}
```